# How to get mods without a (version).jar folder in my .minecraft folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to get mods, and I know that the bin is gone. I don't even have the (version).jar folder in my .minecraft folder.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to Arqade.  I don't know much about Minecraft, but these kinds of questions generally work better if you:  first, explain what you are trying to do and what you expect to happen; second, explain what actually happens; third, explain what you've tried to get around the problem and what happens then.  Sometimes, the error message that you get is misleading and can send you down the wrong path.  Therefore, it's better to tell us the exact error message and let the readers diagnose it rather than asking us to help you fix what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac the .minecraft folder is located at ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft
If you are on windows and there is no .minecraft under %appdata% then re-install minecraft as you probably accidentally deleted it. :(

EDIT: There is no Version.jar. Your Minecraft.jar is located IN you version folder and then the version of minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

.jar is a file extension, meaning that you are looking for your Minecraft.jar *file*. This can be opened in an extraction program like winRAR or 7zip, giving access to the mods you are trying to install.